# How to access Apache session information from python

Tags: python, apache, session

I am maintaining a web application built in python.

Access control for the app is handled at the Apache layer (using the Apache htpasswd file).

Right now, the app works the same no matter who is using it. The app doesn't even know who is logged in. But now I need to add a feature to the app that requires knowing who is logged in.

So the question is this: is there some way to access the Apache session information and see the user name of the user logged i non this session?

Of course I could completely redo the security model so that the app handles user login, but if there is any way to just access the Apache info, that will save me lots of work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Basic Auth, you can check the `Authorization` HTTP header:

```
>>> request.headers["Authorization"]
'Basic YWRtaW46aHVudGVyMg=='
>>> request.headers["Authorization"].partition(" ")[2].decode("base64")
'admin:hunter2'
```

Alternatively, you can check the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable (although this isn't *guaranteed* to be set in the same way tha the `Authorization` header will be):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['REMOTE_USER']
'admin'
```